# Array of STL List not accessing List functions

Tags: c++, arrays, list, stl

I have an array of lists:

```
int* adj;
std::list<int> adj[n];//where n is the size of the array
```

My problem is that when I need `adj[v].size()` where v is the index I am currently at, I get the error :

```
request for member 'size' in '((GenericClass*)this)->GenericClass::adj', which is of non-class type 'int*' for(int i=0; i<adj.size(); ++i)
```

I similarly get this problem for each other function I try to access in the STL List class. I tried to create an iterator as well:

```
 for(std::list<int>::iterator it=adj[v].begin(); it != adj[v].end(); ++it)
```

but I am getting the same problem as stated before.

Edit: in the private of my class I have:
int* adj;

then in one of my functions, after I get the size of my array from the user, I have
the `std::list<int> adj[n]` line.

EDIT 2:

I have now changed my private to read :`typedef std::list<int> IntList;
        typedef std::vector<IntList> AdjVec;
        AdjVec adj;`

I have a function in my public, int GenericClass::search(AdjVec adj, int v)
And I get an error

`'AdjVec' has not been declared
   int search(AdjVec adj, int v);
              ^
GenericClass.cc:234:20: error: no matching function for call to 'GenericClass::search(GenericClass::AdjVec&, int&)'
    u= search(adj, v);`

Comment: get rid of the `int* adj;`? Why do you even have that?

Comment: "I have an array of lists:" What you have is a duplicate identifier compilation error. I'd start by fixing that. `adj` is defined multiple times.

Comment: "array of lists:" can you show full declarations of mentioned data structures?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to access a member method `size()` on an `int`.

```
int* adj;
```

You've redefined (or not defined the list) for the variable `adj`. The compiler thinks you're talking about `int* adj` and not `std::list<int> adj[n];`

Get rid of the first definition and use the second.

**EDIT:**
Seems like you don't know what `n` will be at compile time, and `adj` is a member of one of your classes. In this case, just use a `vector` and dynamically resize it at runtime.

```
// In your header.
typedef std::list<int> IntList;
typedef std::vector<IntList> AdjVec;
AdjVec adj;

// In your cpp, when you know what 'n' is.
adj.resize(n);
adj[0].size();
```

Comment: int* adj is declared in the private of my class. If I used the second definition in the private, I don't know what n will be yet at the compilation. Is there a way to get around that?

Comment: @Walter - Made some edits that will hopefully clear that up for you.

Comment: @Walter To be consistent with this approach, it will mean creating a `setListSize(int indexPosition, int listLen)` method, or similarly named public member function to pass the `listLen` value for each list in the vector of lists.  Alternatively, if it is not important to set a predetermined value for each list's element quantity, then add/remove elements to the appropriate list as needed.

Comment: The problem I seem to be getting now is that when I use this method, everywhere throughout my code it tells me AdjVec has not been declared.

Comment: @Walter The new AdjVec instance is part of the `GenericClass` definition (e.g. private access)?

Comment: Correct. I put it in the private of the class.